# spring boot: what dependencies are needed make a simple spring boot app with domain objects, ORM and web services (similar to grails?)

Tags: spring-boot, grails

I come from grails where all config and setup is done for you, and you just write domain code (such as domain objects, services and controllers). No plugins, no mvn configuration, no pain.

Now I'm trying to setup a spring boot project, where i can just add domain objects, and the framework handles creating them in a database, creating indexes and relationships etc (i.e. hibernate), and I can just query the data with java instead of hand writing sql.

Following this tutorial to create a spring boot project: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-spring-boot

It says "install the required dependencies", and there is a very long list, including things like:

1. spring web
2. spring boot dev tools
3. spring configuration processor
4. spring session
5. spring web services
6. spring security
7. JDBC api
8. spring data JPA

etc.
etc.

I had assumed spring boot had everything you need already included, including hibernate, JDBC, web services etc to write a web application with domain objects and automatic persistence.

Am I wrong?  is spring boot nothing more than a bare spring app, where you have to manually install every required dependency (requiring significant expertise and knowlege), even JDBC?

How do I know which of the many dependencies I need to make a spring boot app, so I can just start coding, and which "come with" the spring boot application (if any).